# Tracking item within a collection on WP7

Tags: vb.net, collections, windows-phone-7, indexing

I'm building a WP7 (VB.NET) app and have a custom class, PinInfo, of which I have two ObservableCollections, TempPins and FavoritePins.

In various parts of the app, I need a unique identifier to get a reference to a particular PinInfo in the collection, so at present, I assign an ID to the PinInfo when it's added to the collection, then later get a reference to the pin via the ID.

For example, if I create a button to delete a pin, I set its tag to the pin's ID, then the button click handler reads the button's tag to get the corresponding pin from the collection (via LINQ).

I generate the ID by adding one to the last-assigned ID, but these lists are often modified (i.e. items removed), so I end up with needlessly large ID numbers (e.g. just a few items, with IDs in the thousands).

How can I structure this better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [Guid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) instead of an integer ID.